# How do I convert raw Electric field wave data into a frequency spectrum?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, computational-physics

My collaborator performed some FDTD simulations for me and sent me the E-field information by mistake instead of the frequency spectrum collected at a certain point.

What is the best way to convert the E vs t data at this point into a frequency spectrum as you would expect from something like a spectrometer?

I assume I should fourier transform and obtain an RMS value of the results?

Comment: A spectrogram is created using the short-time Fourier transform, though many of the modern software packages have built-in spectrogram functionalities that you can use on the go. It depends on what software you're using.

Comment: http://faculty.jsd.claremont.edu/jmilton/Math_Lab_tool/Labs/Lab9.pdf, for example.